# Implement iOS home screen folder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collectionView with each cell showing an image. I want to implement a drag and drop. This will solve two purpose.

- Rearrange cells.
- When a image is dragged into other, it forms a collection (think of it as a group containing two or more images).

This behavior is inline with the home screen folder where app icon can be grouped into folders.

Please suggest how I can implement this.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't trivial but it is not impossible either.

Reordering is simpler, and you can take advantage of UICollectionView's methods:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177-CH1-SW67

> **Reordering Items Interactively**
>
> Collection views allow you to move
> items around based on user interactions. Normally, the order of items
> in a collection view is defined by your data source. If you support
> the ability for users to reorder items, you can configure a gesture
> recognizer to track the user’s interactions with a collection view
> item and update that item’s position.
>
> To begin the interactive repositioning of an item, call the
> beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath: method of the collection
> view. While your gesture recognizer is tracking touch events, call the
> updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition: method to report changes in
> the touch location. When you are done tracking the gesture, call the
> endInteractiveMovement or cancelInteractiveMovement method to conclude
> the interactions and update the collection view.
>
> During user interactions, the collection view invalidates its layout
> dynamically to reflect the current position of the item. If you do
> nothing, the default layout behavior repositions the items for you,
> but you can customize the layout animations if you want. When
> interactions finish, updates its data source object with the new
> location of the item.
>
> The UICollectionViewController class provides a default gesture
> recognizer that you can use to rearrange items in its managed
> collection view. To install this gesture recognizer, set the
> installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement property of the
> collection view controller to YES.

To implement the "grouping" behavior, you need to define your cell in such a way that it can determine whether it is a single item and should just display itself, or if it consists of multiple items, in which case it should be able to pop up a view to act as a tray, possibly its own view controller to handle taps independently.  This part is going to be hard as you'll need to implement reordering again, and dragging out, etc.

You might want to search Github and others to see if anyone has implemented a "Springboard" type of app that can get you started.